# How to predict KW rating and rated current when there is no nameplate on a three phase induction motor?

Tags: motor, three-phase, induction-motor

I came accross the following tasks during my trainee period in an electrical firm. I was provided motor with no nameplate in  following conditions:

1. When I can remove the mechanical load from the motor, so that i can run it on no load.
2. When i cant remove the mechanical load from the motor shaft. That is, i need to predict the Motor KW and current rating at loaded condition.
3. When the motor is defective, that is it is not starting( or i cant start it for some reason like overcurrent etc)

My questions are:

1. How to predict(calculate) the KW rating and current rating of motor in above three conditions?
2. If in any case i am unable to predict current rating then how do i know what size of Breaker and protection do i need for safe testing of that motor ?
3. Can i calculate the KW rating using physical size and parameters of a motor?

Umer.

Comment: If there is no information whatsoever, it seems like it would be pretty difficult. On the other hand, if the motor is in use, then you can measure the amps under load. That is something. You can compare with other motors with similar size and amp rating. If you know the volts the motor needs, you can apply the voltage and measure no load amps. I have never faced this situation and not sure what I would do.

Comment: This is a rather disorganized collection of several questions. One post here is supposed to contain only one question along with all of the information available. For study and homework questions, you need to present your effort to solve the problem.